# Remove spike noise from data in Python

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, noise

I'm transitioning all of my data analysis from MATLAB to Python and I've finally hit a block where I've been unable to quickly find a turnkey solution.  I have time series data from many instruments including an ADV (acoustic doppler velocimeter) that require despiking.  Previously I've used this function in MATLAB that works quite well:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15361-despiking

Is anybody aware of a similar function available in Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [median filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.median_filter.html), and there are plenty of options depending on your data class, for example

```
import scipy.ndimage as im
x= im.median_filter(x, (self.m,self.m))
```

Comment: I played around with a moving average originally, but wasn't quite getting the results similar to what I was with the MATLAB code.  It looks like the median_filer will work for now, thanks.